# Redefine the \AtBeginShipout command (eso-pic, atbegshi)

Tags: eso-pic

I don't understand how to redefine/clear/reset a running `\AtBeginShipout`-command.

So far, I've used `\AtBeginShipout{\AddToShipoutPicture*{...}}` to place proper images running through the document, but now I tried to redefine the pictures in the second part of my document –- without success. `\ClearShipoutPicture` takes no effect at all. I studied the documentation of `atbegshi` over and over ...

I would be glad, if somebody could give me some assistance.

Comment: I do not understand your use of `\AtBeginShipout{\AddToShipoutPicture*{...}}`, why do you add it to the shipout? It slready does the it self. Perhaps you should be a bit more detailed about what it it you are trying to do

Comment: well, I used it to handle multiple states generated with a ifelse-loop. nevertheless, you gave me a hint by mentioning the  doubling which results an unbreakable loop. I solved the problem by writing the ifelse-statement inside the `\AddToShipoutPicture{}`... thanks once again ;)